# Fast enumeration situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, fast-enumeration

I'm currently working with fast enumeration variables, something that seems really simple I can't make it work.

I have this code, that it work

```
for (NSDictionary *story in stories){

    NSLog(@"%@", [story objectForKey:@"title"]);

}
```

This actually prints every single key stored in tittle. Now, I try to do this

```
for (NSDictionary *story in stories){

    NSLog(@"%@", [story objectForKey:@"title"]);

    NSString *titles = [story objectForKey:@"title"];

    [self.bigText setText:titles];
}
```

And it just print one. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, figured it out myself.

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];


for (NSDictionary *story in stories){

    NSLog(@"%@", [story objectForKey:@"title"]);

    [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [story objectForKey:@"title"]]];
}

self.bigText.text = string;
```

Comment: Two things: Use modern syntax: `NSLog("%@", story[@"title"]);`. Don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat`. Just do: `[string appendString:story[@"title"]];`. BTW - if you really need a string format, use `NSMutableString appendFormat:`. No need to use `stringWithFormat:` in such a case.

Comment: @rmaddy I was just testing `NSLog("%@", story[@"title"]);` and xcode says "incompatible pointers types passing "char[3]" to paramater type ID

Comment: Oops - typo. You need `NSLog(@"%@", story[@"title"]);`.

Comment: I didn't see it either. Thanks